SFDC data in tableau prep builder
while connecting to tableau prep builder, not able to export all SFDC objects data? what can be the problem. what can be other way to get database from SFDC, GA4, google AdWords, marketo, SEMrush and other data bases?
trying to create a central database of all marketing data source
